# In Excel VSTO Document-Level Customizations, how do I pass "Globals.Sheetn" to parameters expecing an Excel.Worksheet interface?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

When I'm writing code in the partial class file for a worksheet (Sheet8, for instance), how do I pass "this" class as an argument expecting objects with the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet interface?

Here's an example of from the Sheet8.cs file:

```
public partial class Sheet8
{
    private void Sheet8_startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var object = new MyCustomClass(this);
    }
}
```

And the consuming code that I'd like to write:

```
class MyCustomClass
{
    public MyCustomClass(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet)
    {
        // Do something with the sheet
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be that "this" always refers to the Sheet*n* object, and cannot be cast to the interface type necessary for creating loosely-coupled interfaces with custom code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

After weeks of searching, I figured it out. It's actually embarrassingly simple.

Each `Globals.SheetN` object has an InnerObject() method that returns an object with the right interface. An example of how to use it:

```
public partial class Sheet8
{
    Sheet8_startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var sheet = new MyCustomClass(InnerObject());
    }
}
```

From there, you can build loosely-coupled, custom objects to your heart's content!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `this` keyword instead of `InnerObject()`.

```
public partial class Sheet8
{
        Sheet8_startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var sheet = new MyCustomClass(this);
    }
}
```

Then, for the constructor of your consuming class use the `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.WorksheetBase` type (instead of the `Worksheet` type).

```
class MyCustomClass
{
    public MyCustomClass(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorksheetBase sheet)
    {
        // Do something with the sheet
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave that a shot in my journey. However, I had trouble with that in document-level customizations. I couldn't specify `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheet` as an interface because `this` often got interpreted as `MyNameSpace.Sheetn`. Is there a way to cast `this` to the PIA interface safely that I'm not aware of? (I'm new to C# and .NET, so these might just be growing pains. Thanks for your help!)

Comment: @theutz, the issue is your consuming class is constructed with the `Worksheet` type. Try changing that to `WorksheetBase` and you should be good to go. I missed that originally and edited my answer accordingly. `WorksheetBase` should have what you need. It is the base class for the Sheetn classes. [WorksheetBase Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheetbase.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've used that before, but it's my (limited) understanding that it's better to use an interface than a specific type for loose-coupling in code. Can you shed some light on that for me in this situation?